# JavaScript code works only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code which creates a new line of text fields, say if the row has specified 4 text fields, the below code creates additional line same as above when I click the [Add] button.

The following code is working only in IE, it does not work in any other browser:

```
var delName = "ID=oth4del";
var t = oth4;
t.str = "\r\n      <td><table class=\"query\" width=\"100%\">\r\n          <tr>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q269r1491i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\">\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q270r1447i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\">\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2765r6758i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\">\r\n              </font></td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n        </table></td>\r\n      ";
t.str = '<table width="100%"><tr chooserroot="true"><td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="delrow(this)" '+delName+'></td>'+t.str+'</tr></table>';
t.cnt = 1;
document.multis.push(t);
```

Error I get is this:

> TypeError: m.lastChild.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function [Break On
>   This Error]

```
m.lastChild.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', m.str.replace(/~/g,++m.cnt));
```

Code for Add button:

The following functions get called:

```
<table align="center"><tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addrow(this)" ID="insurance1Add"
></td></tr></table>


document.multis = new Array();

function findparent(e,tn) {
  while(e && e.parentNode && e.tagName && e.tagName.toLowerCase()!=tn) e = e.parentNode;
  return e;
}

function addrow(b) 
{
  var m = findparent(b,"div");  
  m.lastChild.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', m.str.replace(/~/g,++m.cnt));    
 }
///////////////////////////////////DEL ROW
function delrow(b)
{
  var table = findparent(b,"table");
  //var t = findparent(b,"div");
  //alert(t.cnt);
  //alert(table.cnt);
  table.parentNode.removeChild(table);  
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'insertAdjacentHTML'

Also I checked again in Chrome and it gave me error on: when addRow is called

HTML generated code:

```
<DIV ID="Div_Insurance" >
        <SPAN id="INSURANCE" style="display:inline;">


<div ID="insurance1"
 >


<table border="1%" align="center" width="100%" style="display:none"><tr>
      <td><table class="query" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td >Type</td>
            <td><select name="q2485i~">
                <option value="5581">Pharmaceutical</option>
                <option value="5582" selected>Long Term Care</option>
                <option value="5583">Home Care</option>
                <option value="5584">Other</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>Other</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2764r6757i~" placeholder="Other Infomation" size="22" maxlength="50"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name of Insurance</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2438r5533i~" placeholder="Insurance Name" size="22" maxlength="50">
            </td>
            <td>Contact Person</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2439r5534i~" placeholder="Contact Person" size="22" maxlength="50">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea cols="20" rows="4"  maxlength="50" name="q2440r5535i~" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2441r5536i~" size="22" maxlength="50" onKeyUp="jm_phonemask(this)" onBlur="wphoneLength(this)"; placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fax</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2442r5537i~" size="22" maxlength="50" onKeyUp="jm_phonemask(this)" onBlur="wphoneLength(this)"; placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX">
            </td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2443r5538i~" size="22" maxlength="50" placeholder="xyz@xyz.xyz">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr></table>

<table align="center"><tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addrow(this)" ID="insurance1Add"
></td></tr></table>

</div>

<script>
var delName = "ID=insurance1del";
var t = insurance1;
t.str = "\r\n      <td><table class=\"query\" width=\"100%\">\r\n          <tr>\r\n            <td >Type</td>\r\n            <td><select name=\"q2485i~\">\r\n                <option value=\"5581\">Pharmaceutical</option>\r\n                <option value=\"5582\" selected>Long Term Care</option>\r\n                <option value=\"5583\">Home Care</option>\r\n                <option value=\"5584\">Other</option>\r\n              </select>\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td>Other</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2764r6757i~\" placeholder=\"Other Infomation\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\"></td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n          <tr>\r\n            <td>Name of Insurance</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2438r5533i~\" placeholder=\"Insurance Name\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\">\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td>Contact Person</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2439r5534i~\" placeholder=\"Contact Person\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\">\r\n            </td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n          <tr>\r\n            <td>Address</td>\r\n            <td><textarea cols=\"20\" rows=\"4\"  maxlength=\"50\" name=\"q2440r5535i~\" placeholder=\"Address\"></textarea>\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td>Phone</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2441r5536i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\" onKeyUp=\"jm_phonemask(this)\" onBlur=\"wphoneLength(this)\"; placeholder=\"XXX-XXX-XXXX\">\r\n            </td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n          <tr>\r\n            <td>Fax</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2442r5537i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\" onKeyUp=\"jm_phonemask(this)\" onBlur=\"wphoneLength(this)\"; placeholder=\"XXX-XXX-XXXX\">\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td>Email</td>\r\n            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"q2443r5538i~\" size=\"22\" maxlength=\"50\" placeholder=\"xyz@xyz.xyz\">\r\n            </td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n        </table></td>\r\n      ";
t.str = '<table width="100%"><tr chooserroot="true"><td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="delrow(this)" '+delName+'></td>'+t.str+'</tr></table>';
t.cnt = 1;
document.multis.push(t);
</script>


      </SPAN>
      </DIV>
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'insertAdjacentHTML'" Cannot be more specific. Replace this function with crossbrowser equivalent as innerHTML, AppendChild, ...

Comment: @roasted `insertAdjacentHTML` since FF8 and Chrome 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Nice info @TerryYoung !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `addrow()` function, do a `console.log(m.lastChild)` and see what it is.

Check its `nodeType`. I suspect it is a Text Node (i.e. nodeType = 3).

Since it is a text node, **not** an Element Node, then of course it wouldn't have the `insertAdjacentHTML` method.

References:

- lastChild: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.lastChild
- nodeType: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType
- insertAdjacentHTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML

---

Here's a classic, old-school snippet you might want to keep. After you get the lastChild (or any other flavors), ensure you're working on an **Element Node**.

```
function addrow(b) {
    var m = findparent(b,"div"),
        lastChildElement = m.lastChild;

    // the old-school routine
    while (lastChildElement && lastChildElement.nodeType !== 1) {
        lastChildElement = lastChildElement.previousSibling;
    }

    if (lastChildElement) {
        lastChildElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', m.str.replace(/~/g,++m.cnt));    
    } else {
        // handle this case...
    }
}
```

And as you might have already guessed, the opposite end would involve `firstChild` and `nextSibling`.

Comment: ok, Thanks, ok, i just did accepted the answer, Thanks Terry young